# How do I only keep observations based on the max values after their decimal point?

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I want to make this dataframe:

(edited to show that it's an actual data frame with more than 1 column)

```
ID = c(100.00, 100.12, 100.36, 101.00, 102.00, 102.24, 103.00, 103.36, 103.90)
blood = c(55, 54, 74, 42, 54, 45, 65, 34, 44)
df = data.frame(ID, blood)

  ID       blood
1 100.00    55
2 100.12    54
3 100.36    74
4 101.00    42
5 102.00    54
6 102.24    45
7 103.00    65
8 103.36    34
9 103.90    44
```

Become this one:

```
ID = c(100.36, 101.00, 102.24, 103.36)
df2 = data.frame(ID)

  ID2        blood2
1 100.36     74
2 101.00     42
3 102.24     45
4 103.90     44
```

In other words, for any given whole number (like 102) I only want to keep the highest decimal version of it. So basically I need to tell R to only keep the highest "version" of each whole number. Any ideas how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
> ID = c(100.00, 100.12, 100.36, 101.00, 102.00, 102.24, 103.00, 103.36)
> ID2 <- tapply( ID, floor(ID), FUN=max)
> ID2
   100    101    102    103 
100.36 101.00 102.24 103.36 
> (df2 <- data.frame(ID2))
       ID2
100 100.36
101 101.00
102 102.24
103 103.36
> (df2 <- data.frame(ID=as.vector(ID2)))
      ID
1 100.36
2 101.00
3 102.24
4 103.36
```

**expanded**

```
> ID = c(100.00, 100.12, 100.36, 101.00, 102.00, 102.24, 103.00, 103.36, 103.9)
> blood = c(55, 54, 74, 42, 54, 45, 65, 34, 44)
> df = data.frame(ID, blood)
> 
> tmp <- tapply( df$ID, floor(df$ID), FUN=function(x) x==max(x))
> 
> (df2 <- df[unlist(tmp),])
      ID blood
3 100.36    74
4 101.00    42
6 102.24    45
9 103.90    44
```

Comment: This might be the most efficient answer, just wondering how I modify it if I have other data associated with the columns? (I edited the original question to show this)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution using the `dplyr` package.

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(pre = floor(ID), post = ID - floor(ID)) %>%
  arrange(pre, desc(post)) %>%
  group_by(pre) %>%
  filter(row_number() == 1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(ID)
```

Comment: To understand how this works, run up to any step in the chain and view `df2`.

Comment: Lovely, and it looks like I just use select(ID, x, y, z) to keep the rest of the columns associated with the rows I want to keep. Thank you

Comment: @StatsNTats Please choose this or any of the other answers as accepted, whichever works for you best.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `base R`

```
df[with(df, ave(ID, floor(ID), FUN = max) == ID),, drop = FALSE]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
> df$X<- gsub("\\.\\d*", "", as.character(df$ID))
> df <- aggregate(ID~X, df, max)
> df$X <- NULL
> df
      ID
1 100.36
2 101.00
3 102.24
4 103.36
```

Answer (score 1):

An option using `dplyr` can be as:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(IntPart = floor(ID)) %>%
  filter(ID == max(ID)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-IntPart) %>%
  as.data.frame() 

#       ID blood
# 1 100.36    74
# 2 101.00    42
# 3 102.24    45
# 4 103.90    44
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `aggregate`:

```
subset(df, ID %in% aggregate(ID ~ floor(df$ID), df, max)$ID)
#       ID blood
# 3 100.36    74
# 4 101.00    42
# 6 102.24    45
# 9 103.90    44
```